# Find cells in column 2 that have the same value in column 1 and save them to a list that can be looped through

Tags: excel, vba

| Board | Subsystem | Min | Max | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AX |  | 10 | 40 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-11 |  | 10 | 400 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-12 |  | 100 | 750 | 100 | 750 |
| AX-13 |  | 10 | 550 | 10 | 550 |
| AX-4 |  | 10 | 400 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-6 |  | 125 | 550 | 125 | 550 |
| AX-6 | WD298588 | 40 | 500 | 40 | 500 |
| AX-6 | WD1234 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| AX-7 |  | 125 | 750 | 125 | 750 |
| AX-8 |  | 125 | 550 | 125 | 550 |

Using the table above, I am looking for a macro that will read the value of `boardtype` from the input when the function is called, and then if `boardtype` appears more than once in column 1, I then need it to check if it has a value for `subsysnum` in column 2. Currently, my function looks for `boardtype` if it cant find a match to `boardtype` it will throw an error. If it can find `boardtype` then it will look for if it appears multiple times in the column. If it doesnt, then it finds the cell value of that row and column 3 "Min" or whatever other column index is specific. Where I am struggling is writing the if `boardtype` appears in multiple times in column 1, then check what the values are in column 2. So for this case, say `boardtype = "AX-6"` and it appears in multiple lines in column 1, so now I need to look at column 2 for rows 7 through 9 and see if and of the values in the cells is a partial match to the input value of `subsysnum = "WD2985"`. For this case, there is a partial match in row 8, which would mean that the function returns the value for row 8, column 3 for Min of 40.

This is what my code looks like at the moment. If anyone could provide help with the method of approach that I am currently doing that would be great. Other have responded to previous posts with different methods, however, I need to do it this way in order to have my error handling method work.

```
Function GetExternalClock(wbSearc As Workbook, boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, column As Long, Optional partialFirst As Boolean = False) As Double 
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, board_range As Range, firstAddress As String, subsysnum_range As Range
    FunctionName = "GetExternalClock"
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\LookupTable.xlsx")
    Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("External Clock")

    Set r1 = ws.Columns(1)
    Set r2 = ws.Columns(2)

    With r1
        Set board_range = r1.Find(What:=boardtype, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) ' find board type row

            If Not board_range Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = board_range.Address ' save board type address
            Else
                    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "Board " & boardtype & " could not be found in lookup table" & vbNewLine ' if no PCB found throw error
                Exit Function
            End If
        Do While Not board_range Is Nothing ' while board type is not nothing look for value of cell in column 2
Dim boardrange_rows As Double, subnum As Double
        boardrange_rows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r1, boardtype) 
        If boardrange_rows = 1 Then ' if boardtype only appears once in table
            GetExternalClock = ws.cells(board_range.row, column).value
        ElseIf boardrange_rows > 1 Then
       
Dim value_range As Long
            value_range = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            For x = 2 To value_range
                boardrow = board_range.row
'               If InStr(subsysnum, ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value) > 0 Then
'                Debug.Print ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value
                Debug.Print boardrow
                If ws.cells(boardrow, 2) Like "*" & subsysnum & "*" Then
'                If subsysnum Like "*" & ws.cells(boardrow, 2) & "*" Then
                Debug.Print "TEST2"
'                If ws.cells(value.row, 2) = subsysnum Then
                    GetExternalClock = ws.cells(boardrow, column).value
                    Debug.Print GetExternalClock
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    MsgBox "Bad"
                End If
            Next x
'            subnum = ws.cells(boardrange_rows, 2)
            
        End If
        boardrange_rows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r1, boardtype) ' counts the number of rows that has boardtype value
        If boardrange_rows = 1 Then ' if boardtype only appears once in table
            GetExternalClock = ws.cells(board_range.row, column).value
        Else
        ' ### if boardrange_rows > 1 Then 
        ' ### look if the values in column 2 lookup table are a partial match to the input `subsysnum` 
        ` ### if yes then get the cell value at (row index, column) 
        ` ### else use the cell value of `boardtype` with a blank cell next to it in column 2 
        End If
        Exit Do 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The sub below is not directly helping you in writing your function. But if I understand you correctly, maybe you want to have a look if the image below is similar with your expected result.

[image]

From the image above, your expected result is 25, 50, 75 and 100 which are coming from column C if the boardtype is "ddd" and in column B of the respected row contains "WD2985"

```
Sub test()
Dim rgData As Range: Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range
Dim BoardType As String: Dim SubSysNum As String
Dim arr: Dim c As Range

Set rgData = Range("A2:A15")
BoardType = "ddd"
SubSysNum = "WD2985"

Set c = rgData.Find(BoardType, lookat:=xlWhole)
If c Is Nothing Then MsgBox "error": Exit Sub

    With rgData
        .Replace BoardType, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
        .Replace True, BoardType, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
If Application.CountA(rg) = 1 Then
    arr = Array(c.Value, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, c.Offset(0, 2).Value)
    Range("E1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = arr
Else
    For Each cell In rg.Offset(0, 1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
        If InStr(cell.Value, SubSysNum) Then
            arr = Array(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, cell.Value, cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            Range("E1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = arr
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

The code replace the "ddd" value in column A into TRUE, then it set the range of cell which has TRUE value as rg variable offset(0,1), then it put back the "ddd" from TRUE.

Then it loop to each cell in rg variable, checking if the cell value contains "WD2985". If yes, then it put the result in column E-F-G.

Please be noticed, the code above don't bother what is in column B if the "ddd" appears only one in column A. It will directly get the value in column C where the row of "ddd" is.

Another way, maybe you can try the Find and then loop with FindNext method.
On each found cell with "ddd" value in column A, check if the cell.offset(0,1) value contains "WD2985". If yes then get the value of the cell.offset(0,2).

Comment: After reviewing your response, I have tried implementing both `If InStr` function and `Like` function, however neither are returning the value I am looking for. I have updated my code above to show the changes I have made. The area where I am struggling for the `If InStr` is  when I call it like this `If InStr(subsysnum, ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value) > 0 Then` it returns a value of 1, however it should be a value of 0 since `ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value` is a blank cell

Comment: maybe you check first `if ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value <> "" and InStr(subsysnum, ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value) > 0` ?

Comment: Or would you recommend the approach using `Like` for instance `If ws.cells(boardrow, 2) Like "*" & subsysnum & "*" Then`